# Save data over json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, grails, grails-2.0

I am using `grails 2.3.4` as the backend for my `angularjs 1.2.8` application.

I want to save my data into a database. I tried to implement it like this:

```
testApp.controller('testController', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location) {
$scope.product = {};

$scope.saveProduct = function() {
    console.log('call saveProduct');
    $http
     .post($rootScope.appUrl + '/product.json', $scope.book)
     .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $location.path('/product');
     }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });
}
```

});

In principle this should work, because my backend uses `@Resource(uri='/product')` to provide a RESTFUL API. I can call all existing products like this: `http://localhost:8080/testApplication/product.json`

However the chrome console diagnosis gives me:

`POST http://localhost:8080/testApplication/undefined/product.json 404 (Not Found)`

The `undefined` makes this link not work. Any suggestions how to remove it?

Any suggestions for how I can change my function to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `$rootScope.appUrl` is `undefined` when you call `$http.post()`. Try logging the value of `$rootScope.appUrl` to the console to make sure. If it's `undefined`, set it to whatever you need to match the URL that your backend expects.

---

Edit: I'm not familiar with the specifics of Angular or what exactly gets passed to this method, but you can be a little more robust by checking to see if the variable is defined, like this:

```
$scope.saveProduct = function() {
  var url = 'products.json';

  if($rootScope && $rootScope.appUrl) {
    url = $rootScope.appUrl + '/' + url;
  }

  console.log('call saveProduct');
  $http
  .post(url, $scope.book)
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $location.path('/product');
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! The thing is that the only word that seperated me from saving is the `undefined`. This url would save my data: `http://localhost:8080/testApplication/product.json` Any suggestions how to kill the undefined in javascript?

Comment: Thx for your answer! My problem is that I still get such a link: `http://localhost:8080/product`